# Writing a custom assertion macro

Tags: elixir

Sometimes I have to compare multiline strings in my Elixir tests and it is hard to read when all the lines are printed inline like `line1\nline2\nline3`.

I would like to write a custom test assertion `compare` that shows the LHS and RHS in two columns.

As a starting point I created a macro called `compare` which is identical to `assert`.

```
defmodule CompareAssertion do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      require CustomCompare
      import CustomCompare
    end
  end

  defmacro compare(assertion) do
    case translate_assertion(assertion) do
      nil ->
        quote do
          value = unquote(assertion)

          unless value do
            raise ExUnit.AssertionError,
              expr: unquote(Macro.escape(assertion)),
              message: "Expected truthy, got #{inspect value}"
          end

          value
        end

      value ->
        value
    end
  end
  # ... 
end
```

I have a function `render_columns(col_a, col_b)` that renders two strings as columns side-by-side. How can I integrate these two together so that LHS and RHS are shown in two columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not identical to assert. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.2.4/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/assertions.ex#L95

Comment: You should implement a new formatter instead. see https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/cli_formatter.ex

Comment: Thanks @josemrb I'll take a look

Comment: @CoderDennis You're right, I moved over just the parts that dealt with the == comparison. I wasn't interested in the match (=) assert.

Comment: The line I linked to showed an example of extracting the `left` and `right` parts, which I thought might help you. I don't really understand what else you're looking for with this question.